# Dart/Flutter - the method forEach was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the "Child_Name" and "Parent_Name" from firebase rtdb and create a list of the names using ListView.builder. I have done this before in another part of the app and it works perfectly. I am trying to apply the same logic again but I am getting an error.

Error is occurs inside the **setState** where the line **childrenList = Map.from(value)** is.

View of my firebase rtdb
[is here (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0pw3.png)

Error:

```
- [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.
- Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => void)
```

Code(1):

```
    Future<List> getListOfChildren() async {
      print("Getting Children");
      databaseReference
      .child("users")
      .child("Absent_Children")
      .child(formattedDate)
      .onValue
      .listen(
        (event) {
          setState(
            () {
              var value = event.snapshot.value;
              childrenList = Map.from(value)
                  .values
                  .map((e) => Children.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
                  .toList();
          },
        );
      },
    );
    return childrenList;
  }
```

Code(2): Class for the data

```
class Children {
  final String childName;
  final String parentName;

  Children({
    this.childName,
    this.parentName,
  });

  static Children fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return Children(
      childName: json["Child_Name"],
      parentName: json["Parent_Name"],
    );
  }
}
```

Code(4): formattedDate

```
  getTodaysDate() {
    setState(
      () {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        var date = DateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        formattedDate = date.format(now).toString();
      },
    );
  }
```

Code(3): My ListView.builder

```
body: childrenList.isEmpty
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: childrenList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                final Children child = childrenList[index];
                final String childName = child.childName;
                final String parentName = child.parentName;
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 0,
                    child: ExpansionTile(
                      title: Text(
                        childName.toUpperCase(),
                        style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              parentName,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(fontSize: 13),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667227/flutter-firebase-access-data-based-on-the-key) too, it looks like there's no data as `databaseReference.child("users").child("Absent_Children").child(formattedDate)` and your code doesn't handle that situation.

If the absence of data is a normal occurrence, you should check if the snapshot has a value before trying to access its value:

```
  databaseReference
  .child("users")
  .child("Absent_Children")
  .child(formattedDate)
  .onValue
  .listen(
    (event && event.snapshot.exists) { //  add exists check here
      setState(
        () {
          var value = event.snapshot.value;
          childrenList = Map.from(value)
              .values
              .map((e) => Children.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
              .toList();
      },
    );
```

Comment: I understand. What would be the correct way to get the data, as there is data in the database? I use a similar way to get data from the same database but from a different node, the data shows up without a problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem. The problem was with how I was getting the formattedDate (without time). This was the reason no data was being fetched. Thank you.